# PHP PDO Oracle call stored function

Tags: php, oracle, function, pdo

I've got a stored function in my Oracle Database which returns a table (type). When running it in the SQL Developer, it works just fine, but I can't get it to work in PHP with PDO.

**Here is my stored function:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_aktuelle_Menues (p_week INTEGER)
  RETURN TableforAktuelleMenues
IS
  v_week INTEGER := p_week;
  v_table TableforAktuelleMenues;
BEGIN
     SELECT CAST(
            MULTISET(
              SELECT tm.MenueID "ID", men.Bezeichnung "Menuebezeichnung", men.Preis "Preis", TO_CHAR(tm.Datum, 'DY') "Tag"
                    FROM Tagesmenue tm INNER JOIN Menue men ON(tm.MenueID = men.MenueID)
                    WHERE TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(tm.Datum, 'WW')) = (TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'WW')) + TO_NUMBER(v_week))
            ) AS TableforAktuelleMenues)
          INTO v_table 
          FROM dual;
   RETURN v_table;
   COMMIT;
END;
```

**Here is the table type:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TYPE TableforAktuelleMenues AS TABLE OF TypeAktuellesMenue;
```

**...and here is the other type:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TYPE TypeAktuellesMenue
AS OBJECT
(
  MenueId INTEGER,
  Bezeichnung VARCHAR2(45),
  Preis FLOAT,
  Wochentag VARCHAR(2)  
);
```

So, like I mentioned above, the function works just fine when calling it in the SQL Developer with the following **query**:

```
SELECT * FROM table(f_aktuelle_Menues(0));
```

...but it doesn't work in **PHP and PDO** with the following code:

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table(f_aktuelle_Menues(0))");
$query->execute();
print_r($query->fetchAll());
```

This is the **error message** I get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 22814 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-22814:
>   attribute or element value is larger than specified in type ORA-06512:
>   at "EPCOS.F_AKTUELLE_MENUES", line 6
>   (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:148)' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\epcos\home.php:70 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\epcos\home.php(70): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\epcos\home.php on line 70

I hope that somebody could help me :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287875/oracle-sql-ora-22814-attribute-or-element-value-is-larger-than-specified-in-type  Review this and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I saw that before, but it was not possible for me to change the SQL Code to a pipe line statement. However, I managed to solve it by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the **solution** to my problem is very weird and I've managed to solve it by myself.

My Type was defined like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TYPE TypeAktuellesMenue
AS OBJECT
(
  MenueId INTEGER,
  Bezeichnung VARCHAR2(45),
  Preis FLOAT,
  Wochentag VARCHAR(2)  
);
```

So, the size of the column "**Wochentag**" is 2, and that was the problem.

**In SQLDeveloper**, the following function returns '**FR**' for Friday:

```
TO_CHAR(some_date, 'DY')
```

...but when calling the **exact same function** with PDO, we get '**FRI**' for Friday back, which is 3 characters long and too big for our "Wochentag" column.

So, the only thing I had to change was the size of the Wochentag column from 2 to 3 and the code runs.

Comment: Wow that's ugly and hard to find.  Good catch!

Comment: Haha, yeah. It was just a coincidence that I found this solution.